# Where To Stick API Calls In A C# UWP App

Tags: c#, oop, mvvm

I'm starting to wrap my head around object-oriented programming (past has always been more procedural) and MVVM.

I'm somewhat confident in the structure of the local app (classes for models and such), but I'm iffy on connecting to external APIs and retrieving JSON results (I know how to connect, but I'm talking about project structure and such).  I've read about facades and services, but it seems like different people structure things differently.  I'm sure there's not a universal rule, but is there a "best practice"?

Just off the top of my head, it seems like having an API class makes sense.  Everything from the model of that data to connecting to the API could sit there.  It seems like I see people making the connection through their view-model, though.

I'm just looking for some input.  Thanks for any direction.

Comment: So, utilizing an `interface` seems common.

Answer (score 1):

As you can imagine, there are many ways to do it.  Any design is likely to have its pros and cons, and you're probably going to be figuring those out with experience.

One simple approach would be to have a "service" class which is your code's facade to the external service.  The interface for it might be as simple as:

```
interface MyService
{
    void SomeOperation(int someValue);
    string AnotherOperation(double anotherValue);
}
```

The class implementing this service would essentially be a pass-through to the external service.  It would have the responsibility of encapsulating the technology stack which accesses the service, such as an HTTP REST client.

Ideally this fully encapsulates the *technical* aspects of using the service (things like HTTP, JSON, etc.) and exposes only the *logical* aspects of it (well-named methods, accepts and returns domain objects instead of JSON strings, etc.).  That way should you ever swap out the technology you would still retain the same semantic business meanings of things and would only have to change that one implementation behind that interface.

As for where to use the service class, that's often a matter of opinion and really depends on what ultimately makes more sense and is easier to support in your code.  One school of thought is to have the models internally use the service class and everything interacts with the models, another is to have more procedural code somewhere which uses the service and the models equally.  Personally I find the former makes more sense in MVVM and the latter more sense in MVC.  But your mileage may vary.

I would recommend trying to use the service in the models directly if possible, as any procedural code would need to live somewhere and in an MVVM pattern you might find yourself "shoe-horning" that in the wrong places.  How you handle things like dependency injection of the service in your models is another topic entirely, if you're also looking to do that.

Comment: Once you create that `interface`, you must create another class that inherits from it.  Is that correct?  I've seen a lot of `IServiceName` and `ServiceName` (where `ServiceName : IServiceName`).

Answer (score 1):

There's no right answer specifically.. it depends on how your app is already structured and what you're trying to do. For our production UWP app, almost all of our API calls are business object download calls, so we set up a class per call, each of which implements a common interface, like so:

```
interface IDownloadMethod<T> : where T : IPersistable {
   string WebServiceBaseURL { get; set; }
   IEnumerable<T> Download();
   Action<IEnumerable> RepositoryMethod { get; }
}
```

... where `IPersistable` is an interface that represents the data returned by these calls.

We created an abstract base class that implements `IDownloadMethod<T>`, with all of the common functionality:

```
public class AbstractDownloadMethod<T> : IDownloadMethod<T> where T : IPersistable {
   // default implementations of all needed methods

   // the most important one:
   IEnumerable<T> Download() {
      // implementation 
   }
}
```

And then each download method becomes a very simple class:

```
internal class DownloadSomeBusinessObject : AbstractDownloadMethod<SomeBusinessObject>
{
   public DownloadSomeBusinessObject (Action<IEnumerable> handler, string webServiceBaseURL, LoginCredential credential) 
      : base(handler, webServiceBaseURL, credential)
   {
      ActionURL = @"someBusinessObject/";
   }
}
```

We have a long list of such API calls, so we have a `Controller` class that iterates over all of them and calls their `Download()` method, and then saves the results to the repository:

```
// you need to populate methodsList first with all the methods you want to call, then...
foreach (IDownloadMethod<IPersistable> method in methodsList)
{
   Task<IEnumerable<IPersistable>> task = Task.Run(() => method.Download());
   TaskAwaiter<IEnumerable<IPersistable>> awaiter = task.GetAwaiter();
   while (!awaiter.IsCompleted)
   { // busy waiting is terrible.. we know
   }
   IList<IPersistable> genericList = awaiter.GetResult().ToList();

   if (method.RepositoryMethod != null)
   {
      method.RepositoryMethod(genericList);
   }
}
```